# How to hide(or show) a part of the data bound to a repeater using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

Suppose that we have some products and their details in our database. I want products names to appear on the page without their details. And if the user hovers on one of the products, the detail for that specific product slides down. I am using using a repeater to retrieve and show the products' data from the database.

Here's my code:

```
    //this is the html
    <div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="productTiltle">
                <%#Eval("producttitle") %> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="productDetail">
                <%#Eval("productdetail") %>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            <hr />
        </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    //this is the css
    .productTitle
    {
    background-color:#f00;
    font-size:x-large;
    text-align:center;
    }
    .productDetail
    {
    background-color:#ff6a00;
    font-size:large;
    }

    //this is the JQuery
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".productDetail").hide();
        $(".productTiltle").hover(function () {
            $(".productDetail").slideDown('normal');
        }, function () {
            $(".productDetail").slideUp('normal');
        }); 
    });
```

I need the repeater to style every row of product I retrieve from the database. But the problem is (as expected), when I use jQuery to do something to the `.productDetail` class, every single element with that class will be affected (in this case, all of the page). But I need some way to use jQuery to do something to a specific product.

e.g if we have products 1 to 100,with `productTitles` of product1,product2,...,product100;and a user hovers on product23,only product23's details show up

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Dude, do you really need jQuery for this? CSS will do it just easy, and the overhead for the browser will be minimum.

Comment: @Adrian Salazar Since they are two separate elements,I can't use css.I could put them in a `div` and then select it using the `div` 's hover state.but that is not what I want.But if you have better idea,I'd be more than happy to know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set like this.

```
.productDetail
    {
       display: none;
       background-color:#ff6a00;
       font-size:large;
    }
```

For Jquery

```
$('.productTiltle').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).next('.productDetail').slideDown('normal');
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).next('.productDetail').slideUp('normal');
  });
```

Comment: Now with the `next` function,it is working!Thanks.Can you tell me what exactly the `next` is doing here?

Comment: did you see that the class is productTiLtle and not productTiTle. may be the code doesn't work because of the misspelling ?

Comment: @kst those are such a happy divs... if you mouse over up/down/up/down/up/down they will be jumping and jumping like happy kids. Sweet!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try jquery hide and show functions?

Comment: the problem is,I don't know how to select the specific product in jquary.All of the product titles have the same class(this is how the asp repeater works).So I can't select them with their classes.If I do,all the titles will be selected!

Answer (score 0):

Give your detail divs data attributes such as:

```
<div class="productTiltle" data-productid="<%# Eval("ProductID") %>">
    <%#Eval("producttitle") %> <br />
</div>

<div class="productDetail" data-productid="<%# Eval("ProductID") %>">
    <%#Eval("productdetail") %>
</div>
```

then in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.productTitle').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var productID = $(this).data('productid');
      $('.productDetail [data-customerID="' + productID + '"]').slideDown();
  });
});
```

NOTE: I have changed to mis-spelled productTiltle to productTitle

Answer (score 0):

Hope this jQuery will help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // this is the jQuery
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".productTiltle").each(function (index) {
                $(this).hover(function () {
                    console.log("slidd");
                    $(".productDetail").eq(index).slideDown('normal');
                }, function () {
                    console.log("slidu");
                    $(".productDetail").eq(index).slideUp('normal');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing better than good old CSS for this thing.

Remember, the less JS that you have in your page, the better. Less maintenance needed and the less headache! And... there's no way in this planet that jQuery might perform better for this than well coded CSS.

HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="productTiltle">
            <%#Eval("producttitle") %> <br />
        </div>
        <div class="productDetail">
            <%#Eval("productdetail") %>
        </div>
       </div> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

CSS:

```
.productTitle
{
  background-color:#f00;
  font-size:x-large;
  text-align:center;
}
.productDetail
{
      background-color:#ff6a00;
  font-size:large;
  display: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .productDetail
{
  display: block;
}
```